# How to use colorstream to stream the RGB data on an image in an WPF kinect application?

Tags: c#, kinect

I want to  view  the stream of the RGB data "color stream" on an image in an WPF kinect application, how can I do this?

Thanks

---

Here is my code and the xaml, so as you can see the skeleton is drawn on an image and what I want is to add the color stream on the image besides the skeleton, so how can I do this?

Many thanks,

```
namespace Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.SkeletonBasics
{
    using System.IO;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using Microsoft.Kinect;
    using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private const float RenderWidth = 640.0f;

        private const float RenderHeight = 480.0f;

        private const double JointThickness = 3;

        private const double BodyCenterThickness = 10;


        private const double ClipBoundsThickness = 10;

        private readonly Brush centerPointBrush = Brushes.Blue;

        private readonly Brush trackedJointBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 68, 192, 68));


        private readonly Brush inferredJointBrush = Brushes.Yellow;

        private readonly Pen trackedBonePen = new Pen(Brushes.Green, 6);
        private readonly Pen trackedBonePenwrong = new Pen(Brushes.White, 6);

        private readonly Pen inferredBonePen = new Pen(Brushes.Gray, 1);


        private KinectSensor sensor;

        private DrawingGroup drawingGroup;


        private DrawingImage imageSource;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static void RenderClippedEdges(Skeleton skeleton, DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Bottom))
            {
                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
                    Brushes.Red,
                    null,
                    new Rect(0, RenderHeight - ClipBoundsThickness, RenderWidth, ClipBoundsThickness));
            }

            if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Top))
            {
                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
                    Brushes.Red,
                    null,
                    new Rect(0, 0, RenderWidth, ClipBoundsThickness));
            }

            if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Left))
            {
                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
                    Brushes.Red,
                    null,
                    new Rect(0, 0, ClipBoundsThickness, RenderHeight));
            }

            if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Right))
            {
                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
                    Brushes.Red,
                    null,
                    new Rect(RenderWidth - ClipBoundsThickness, 0, ClipBoundsThickness, RenderHeight));
            }
        }

        private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Create the drawing group we'll use for drawing
            this.drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();

            // Create an image source that we can use in our image control
            this.imageSource = new DrawingImage(this.drawingGroup);

            // Display the drawing using our image control
            Image.Source = this.imageSource;

            // Look through all sensors and start the first connected one.
            // This requires that a Kinect is connected at the time of app startup.
            // To make your app robust against plug/unplug, 
            // it is recommended to use KinectSensorChooser provided in Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit
            foreach (var potentialSensor in KinectSensor.KinectSensors)
            {
                if (potentialSensor.Status == KinectStatus.Connected)
                {
                    this.sensor = potentialSensor;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (null != this.sensor)
            {
                // Turn on the skeleton stream to receive skeleton frames
                this.sensor.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
        //    this.sensor.ColorFrameReady += this.SensorColorSkeletonFrameReady;
                this.sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();

            //    this.sensor.ColorFrameReady += new EventHandler<ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(kinectSensor_ColorFrameReady);
                // Add an event handler to be called whenever there is new color frame data
                this.sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += this.SensorSkeletonFrameReady;

                // Start the sensor!
                try
                {
                    this.sensor.Start();
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    this.sensor = null;
                }
            }

            if (null == this.sensor)
            {
                this.statusBarText.Text = Properties.Resources.NoKinectReady;
            }
        }
        private void WindowClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (null != this.sensor)
            {
                this.sensor.Stop();
            }
        }

        private void SensorSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            Skeleton[] skeletons = new Skeleton[0];

            using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
            {
                if (skeletonFrame != null)
                {
                    skeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
                    skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);

                }
            }

            using (DrawingContext dc = this.drawingGroup.Open())
            {
                // Draw a transparent background to set the render size
                //dc.DrawImage();
                dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, null, new Rect(0.0, 0.0, RenderWidth, RenderHeight));

                if (skeletons.Length != 0)
                {

                    foreach (Skeleton skel in skeletons)
                    {
                        Skeleton first = FindSkeleton(e);

                        if (first == null)
                            return;

                        int firstSkeleton = first.TrackingId;
                        RenderClippedEdges(skel, dc);

                        if (skel.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
                        {

                            this.DrawBonesAndJoints(skel, dc);


                        }
                        else if (skel.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.PositionOnly)
                        {
                            dc.DrawEllipse(
                            this.centerPointBrush,
                            null,
                            this.SkeletonPointToScreen(skel.Position),
                            BodyCenterThickness,
                            BodyCenterThickness);
                        }

                    }
                }

                // prevent drawing outside of our render area
                this.drawingGroup.ClipGeometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, RenderWidth, RenderHeight));
            }
        }

        private void DrawBonesAndJoints(Skeleton skeleton, DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            // Render Torso
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.Head, JointType.ShoulderCenter);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderLeft);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderRight);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.Spine);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.Spine, JointType.HipCenter);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipLeft);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipRight);

            // Left Arm
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderLeft, JointType.ElbowLeft);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ElbowLeft, JointType.WristLeft);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.WristLeft, JointType.HandLeft);

            // Right Arm
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderRight, JointType.ElbowRight);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ElbowRight, JointType.WristRight);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.WristRight, JointType.HandRight);

            // Left Leg
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipLeft, JointType.KneeLeft);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.KneeLeft, JointType.AnkleLeft);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.AnkleLeft, JointType.FootLeft);

            // Right Leg
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipRight, JointType.KneeRight);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.KneeRight, JointType.AnkleRight);
            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.AnkleRight, JointType.FootRight);

            // Render Joints
            foreach (Joint joint in skeleton.Joints)
            {
                Brush drawBrush = null;

                if (joint.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
                {
                    drawBrush = this.trackedJointBrush;                    
                }
                else if (joint.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Inferred)
                {
                    drawBrush = this.inferredJointBrush;                    
                }

                if (drawBrush != null)
                {
                    drawingContext.DrawEllipse(drawBrush, null, this.SkeletonPointToScreen(joint.Position), JointThickness, JointThickness);
                }
            }
        }


        private Point SkeletonPointToScreen(SkeletonPoint skelpoint)
        {
            // Convert point to depth space.  
            // We are not using depth directly, but we do want the points in our 640x480 output resolution.
            DepthImagePoint depthPoint = this.sensor.MapSkeletonPointToDepth(
                                                                             skelpoint,
                                                                             DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);
            return new Point(depthPoint.X, depthPoint.Y);
        }

        private void DrawBone(Skeleton skeleton, DrawingContext drawingContext, JointType jointType0, JointType jointType1)
        {
            Joint joint0 = skeleton.Joints[jointType0];
            Joint joint1 = skeleton.Joints[jointType1];

            // If we can't find either of these joints, exit
            if (joint0.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked ||
                joint1.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Don't draw if both points are inferred
            if (joint0.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Inferred &&
                joint1.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Inferred)
            {
                return;
            }

            // We assume all drawn bones are inferred unless BOTH joints are tracked
            Pen drawPen = this.inferredBonePen;
            if (joint0.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked && joint1.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
            {
               // int uuu=0;
                //if (uuu==0)
                //    drawPen = this.trackedBonePenwrong;
                //else
                drawPen = this.trackedBonePen;
            }

            drawingContext.DrawLine(drawPen, this.SkeletonPointToScreen(joint0.Position), this.SkeletonPointToScreen(joint1.Position));

        }

        private void CheckBoxSeatedModeChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (null != this.sensor)
            {
                if (this.checkBoxSeatedMode.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault())
                {
                    this.sensor.SkeletonStream.TrackingMode = SkeletonTrackingMode.Seated;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.sensor.SkeletonStream.TrackingMode = SkeletonTrackingMode.Default;
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }


    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.SkeletonBasics.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Skeleton Basics" Height="735" Width="1151" Loaded="WindowLoaded" Closing="WindowClosing">

    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MediumGreyBrush" Color="#ff6e6e6e"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="KinectPurpleBrush" Color="#ff52318f"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="KinectBlueBrush" Color="#ff00BCF2"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" x:Key="SquareCheckBox" >
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">
                                <Grid x:Name="SquareCheckBoxChecked">
                                    <Image x:Name="CheckedNormal" Source="Images\CheckedNormal.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Image x:Name="CheckedHover" Source="Images\CheckedHover.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid x:Name="SquareCheckBoxUnchecked" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                    <Image x:Name="UncheckedNormal" Source="Images\UncheckedNormal.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Image x:Name="UncheckedHover" Source="Images\UncheckedHover.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="SquareCheckBoxText" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{StaticResource KinectPurpleBrush}" FontSize="15"  Margin="9,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="SquareCheckBoxChecked"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="SquareCheckBoxUnchecked"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="CheckedNormal"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="UncheckedNormal"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="CheckedHover"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="UncheckedHover"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource KinectBlueBrush}" TargetName="SquareCheckBoxText"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Name="layoutGrid" Margin="10 0 10 0" Width="1094">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="0 0 0 20">
            <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="Images\Logo.png" Stretch="None" Margin="0 10 0 5"/>
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="{StaticResource MediumGreyBrush}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="18">Skeleton Basics</TextBlock>
            <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="Images\Status.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 0 0 5"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Image Name="Image" Width="640" Height="480"/>
        </Viewbox>
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource SquareCheckBox}" Content="Seated Mode" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 10 10 10" Name="checkBoxSeatedMode" Checked="CheckBoxSeatedModeChanged" Unchecked="CheckBoxSeatedModeChanged"/>
        <StatusBar Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="statusBar" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="White" Foreground="{StaticResource MediumGreyBrush}">
            <StatusBarItem Padding="0 0 0 10">
                <TextBlock Name="statusBarText" Margin="0">Click 'Seated' to change skeletal pipeline type!</TextBlock>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>


</Window>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the Microsoft sample? or even internet sample (there is plenty of them out there)

Since you're developing in c# i'll assume you're using WPF & SDK1.0 (or more):

Here is one solution:

first enable the color stream:

```
 KinectSensor kinectSensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];
 kinectSensor.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
 kinectSensor.Start();
 kinectSensor.ColorFrameReady += this.ColorImageReady;
```

then handle the event:

```
    private static readonly int Bgr32BytesPerPixel = (PixelFormats.Bgr32.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
    private byte[] pixelData;
    private WriteableBitmap CameraSource;

private void ColorImageReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
           bool receivedData = false;
            using (ColorImageFrame imageFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
            {
                if (imageFrame != null)
                {

                    if (pixelData == null)
                    {
                        this.pixelData = new byte[imageFrame.PixelDataLength];
                    }

                    imageFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(this.pixelData);
                    receivedData = true;

                    // A WriteableBitmap is a WPF construct that enables resetting the Bits of the image.
                    // This is more efficient than creating a new Bitmap every frame.
                    if (receivedData)
                    {


                    this.CameraSource.WritePixels(
                        new Int32Rect(0, 0, imageFrame.Width, imageFrame.Height),
                        this.pixelData,
                        imageFrame.Width * Bgr32BytesPerPixel,
                        0);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

in your xaml:

```
 <Image Name="Camera" Width="160" Height="120" Margin="0,0,0,0"  RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" />
```

in the code-behind:

```
kinectSensor.ColorFrameReady += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Kinect.ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(ColorImageFrameReady_handler);
```

and the corresponding handler:

```
public void ColorImageFrameReady_handler(object sender, Microsoft.Kinect.ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            Camera.Source = CameraSource;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I won't paste all the code because it's pretty much but Coding 4 Fun has a Kinect for Windows Quickstart Series where they handle RGB video in the video **Camera Fundamentals**

Link to the series : http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart

Link to **Camera Fundamentals** : http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart/Camera-Fundamentals